# Limit of a sequence with the inverse tangential function

Tags: limits

Determine $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that:
$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} N^{\alpha} \sum_{n=1}^N \arctan(n) = \beta $

I tried separating the limits but this didn’t work. Not sure how to proceed with this question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \arctan(n) = \frac\pi 2$, apply [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) and you will have $\alpha = -1$ and $\beta = \frac\pi 2$